# Find regular intervals in a set of unordered numbers

Tags: arrays, sorting, math, language-agnostic, indexing

I have a set of not-unique real numbers read from a file.

All these numbers were generated from a linear space, that is, the difference between numbers is always a multiple from a fixed value, the "step" or "grid size" of the linear space, so to say.

Each existing value will tipically appear many times in the file.

My goal would be to find how the values are spaced, so that I could put each (unique) value in an array and access its value with an index.

Comment: some sample input and output please

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the greatest common divisor of those numbers.  Here it is in Python:

```
def gcd( a, b ):
    "greatest common divisor"
    while True:
        c = a % b
        if c < 1e-5:
            return b
        a, b = b, c

def gcdset( a_set ):
    "use the pairwise gcd to find gcd of a set"
    x = a_set.pop()
    total = x
    for u in a_set:
        x = gcd( u, x )
        # the following step is optional,
        # some sort of stabilization just for improved accuracy
        total = total + u
        x = total / round(total/x)

    return x

# the list where we want to find the gcd
inputlist = [2239.864226650253, 1250.4096410911607, 1590.1948696485413,
    810.0479848807954, 2177.343744595695, 54.3656365691809, 2033.2748076873656,
    2074.049035114251, 108.7312731383618, 2188.216871909531]

# we turn it into a set to get rid of duplicates
aset = set(inputlist)
print(gcdset( aset ))
```

If you don't have Python around you can play with this code here: http://ideone.com/N9xDWA

Comment: Incidentally Python is my preferred programming language. I will test your answer and quickly give some feedback, but that seems to be like what I need. Thanks for now.

Comment: @heltonbiker The gcd can get unstable for many numbers.  I added some code to stabilize it.  Now it should give perfect accuracy.

Comment: Amazing, tomorrow this will be tested for sure. Thanks again.